# How to have two threads running simultaneously? (Visual C++)

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm trying to have two threads running simultaneously, adding and subtracting from an integer. The thought is to have a random sleep time on them so that they will add or subtract while the other is sleeping. So for example if the thread which adds is asleep for let's say 12 seconds, the thread that subtracts can potentially, subtract not just once, but two or three times before the other wakes.

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Threading;

public ref class RunStack {
private: static Semaphore^ stackSemaphor;
         static int itemStack = 10;

public: static void addItem() {
    Random^ Rand = gcnew Random();

    while (true) {
        stackSemaphor->WaitOne();

        int Pause = Rand->Next(1, 10);
        Pause = Pause * 1000;
        Thread::Sleep(Pause);

        itemStack++;

        Console::CursorLeft = 3;
        Console::CursorTop = 3;
        Console::WriteLine("Amount in stack: " + itemStack);

        stackSemaphor->Release();
    }
}

public: static void subItem() {
    Random^ Rand = gcnew Random();

    while (true) {
        stackSemaphor->WaitOne();

        int Pause = Rand->Next(1, 10);
        Pause = Pause * 1000;
        Thread::Sleep(Pause);

        itemStack--;

        Console::CursorLeft = 3;
        Console::CursorTop = 3;
        Console::WriteLine("Amount in stack: " + itemStack);

        stackSemaphor->Release();
    }
}

        void Main() {
            stackSemaphor = gcnew Semaphore(1, 1);

            ThreadStart^ ThreadDelegate1 = gcnew ThreadStart(addItem);
            ThreadStart^ ThreadDelegate2 = gcnew ThreadStart(subItem);

            Thread^ Thread1 = gcnew Thread(ThreadDelegate1);
            Thread1->Priority = ThreadPriority::Normal;
            Thread1->Start();

            Thread^ Thread2 = gcnew Thread(ThreadDelegate2);
            Thread2->Priority = ThreadPriority::Normal;
            Thread2->Start();
        }

};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Console::Title = "ItemStack";

    RunStack^ RunIt = gcnew RunStack();
    RunIt->Main();

    return 0;
}
```

This is what I have so far, but I'm not sure how I will have them not wait for each other. As it stands now it only adds 1, then waits for it to subtract 1 before adding 1, and so on. While I want it to be able to add/subtract even if the other is sleeping, and the one has shorter sleep time. I only want it to happen in increments of 1, and not have it add or subtract a random amount.

Comment: + Why are you using C++/CLI and not either C++ or C#, for what is essentially an algroithmic problem? + Why are you using this semaphore construct?

Comment: Conditional variable along with mutex will help realise your program more easily and effectively.